# Doctrine 2 optimistic locking only on changed fields

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Is anyone aware of any bundle, or of any plans for Doctrine to implement a new optimistic locking strategy like the one in Telerik framework?

http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/developers-guide/crud-operations/concurrency-control/data-access-tasks-define-model-concurrency-optimistic#checking_for_any_changes

This strategy is great because it's not using version numbers, or timestamps, it compares the old values of the inputs with new values, and only for the changed inputs.

So if I have two different forms updating the same entity, using the current strategies (timestamp or versioning), 2 users will get into conflict even if the do not update the same data.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a rather old question on the interwebs, so, I'm going to glaze over how this can be done in theory.

The per column lock implies there is a mechanism for detecting per column changes - therefore either the row is hashed (or the columns we are concerned about) and that hash comparison is used to detect/track changes OR we track each column individually.

This tracking would then have to be applied on a per request basis to determine what's changed, when. This is where the normal @Version decorator logic would apply.

Telerik is able to handle the per column changes because the information is compared (array comparisons, most likely) in the browser. This is an isolated state of the data that is not in sync with other browsers/database until update.

Easiest option here is to not allow the two forms to collide (in terms of data) and remove the lock - OR - decouple the forms data from the primary table and allow them to be updated separately (and merged with a sql join).

Comment: Thanks for reopening the discussion.
The form do collide and that cannot be changed.Think that 2 users can access the same form, editing the same entity. And it happens a lot.
The hashing solution is a good one.